# Add attribute and string to XML File in c#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I looked around the internet but I can't find a solution for my problem, although I guess this should be very simple.

I have a XML document. There two nodes that look like:

```
<Attachments>
  </Attachments>

 <Templates>
  </Templates>
```

After adding two elements to each node, they should look like:

```
<Attachments>
        <Attachment INDEX0="Test1" />
        <Attachment INDEX1="Test2" />
      </Attachments>

     <Templates>
        <Template INDEX0="Test1">EMPTY</Template>
        <Template INDEX0="Test2">EMPTY</Template>
      </Templates>
```

I tried following code for the first one:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.xml"));
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("//Attachments");

    List<String> list = new List<string>() {"Test1","Test2"};

    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Attachment");
        root.AppendChild(elem);
        XmlNode subNode = root.SelectSingleNode("Attachment");
        XmlAttribute xKey = doc.CreateAttribute(string.Format("INDEX{0}", list.IndexOf(item).ToString()));
        xKey.Value = item;
        subNode.Attributes.Append(xKey);
    }
```

but this does absolutely nothing. How can I achieve these two cases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using LINQ to XML unless you have a specific reason you can't.  The old `XmlDocument` API is quite painful to work with:

```
var items = new List<string> {"Test1", "Test2"};

var attachments = items.Select((value, index) =>
    new XElement("Attachment", new XAttribute("INDEX" + index, value)));

var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path/to/file.xml");

doc.Descendants("Attachments")
    .Single()
    .Add(attachments);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4r7HlN) for a working demo.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!

Comment: One question. How do I put an inner text into it. Like in the template node?

Comment: @Canox your best course of action now is to look at some documentation and tutorials around LINQ to XML. To add text to an element, just include some text in the constructor params.  To set the text of an existing element or attribute, set its `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the error. The foreach loop should look like:

```
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement(string.Format("Attachment{0}", list.IndexOf(item)));
            node.AppendChild(elem);
            XmlNode subNode = root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Attachment{0}", list.IndexOf(item)));
            XmlAttribute xKey = doc.CreateAttribute(string.Format("INDEX{0}", list.IndexOf(item).ToString()));
            xKey.Value = item;
            subNode.Attributes.Append(xKey);
        }
```

but I still don't know how to achieve the case with the template attribute in my example.